# "Invalid Argument Exception Route [login] not defined " shown in laravel

Tags: laravel

Trying to learn with Laravel today. I am getting the following error when I try to store sign up data via form to database.thanks...tomorrow is my exam.

InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined.

web.php

```
Route::post('/save_contact', 'HomeController@save_contact');
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Homecontroller.php

```
public function save_contact(Request $request)
    {
       $data=array();
       $data['email']=$request -> email;
         $data['password']=$request -> password;
         DB::table('users')->insert($data);


}
```

}

Comment: In addition to my answer.. do not store plain text password in the DB, that's never a good idea.

Comment: in your save contact form  their is route('login').

Comment: Did you tried `php artisan make:auth` ?

Comment: You'd better show the full web.php file, because probably that's related with auth routing you are including somewhere in that file

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the login route somewhere in your app (maybe a view?) but the a route named "login" has not been defined.

Check your routes/web.php and see if you have a login route with the "login" name.

`Route::get('/login', 'YourController@login')->name('login');`

Comment: i dont have anything which is login..i want to store sign up form data into database...i made route and controller,,,but when i submit my form than it shows r=login not found..but i did not use anything related to login

Comment: You might add a login route in your view, remove that for eliminating the error

Comment: @mdhasanuzzaman you should probably provide with the content of your views. It really sounds like you're trying to load up a route called login but you didn't define one.